# Add(not concatenate) a number to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qbytearray

I have the following `QByteArray`:

```
QByteArray ba;
ba.resize(3);
ba[0]=ba[2]=0x8a;
ba[1]=0x0d;          //so ba=8a0d8a
```

I want to add a hexadecimal number to the above `QByteArray`. For eg. on adding 0x01, `ba` should contain `8a0d8b`. Any such operation involving carry should be propagated forward as in a normal hex addition. I have tried using `+` operator:

```
ba=ba+1;
```

but it concatenates (resulting in `8a0d8a01` in the above case) instead of performing actual operation. How can this be done ?

Comment: Should the byte array always have three elements?

Comment: It can have 3 or 4 elements. Not more

Comment: But maybe it's better to write a class that will store and operate with numbers directly and return them as a byte array if requested?

Comment: I was hoping for some inbuilt function to do it. Else I can go for the more manual byte wise addition inside a for loop but that means unnecessarily complicating the code

Comment: Well, what will be the result of adding `0x01` to `8a0dff` with your approach?

Comment: will add `0x01` to previous byte if current byte addition results in `0x00`

Comment: Do you really need make math on QByteArray? Why not to do this with lets say long and shift to needed position?

Comment: A lot of my code deals with hex value. Converting and reconverting would be tedious work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the easiest solution:

```
uint32_t num = (b[3] << 24) + (b[2] << 16) + (b[1] << 8) + (b[0]);
num++; // add one
b[0] = num & 0xff;
b[1] = (num >> 8) & 0xff;
b[2] = (num >> 16) & 0xff;
b[3] = (num >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Basically you convert to an arithmetic integer back and forth. Just make sure you don't overflow. This is a simple example. You can make it a class with a state that returns `QByteArray` on some method or you can make a function that does this once at a time.

Comment: A simple solution, as long as endianness of the data does not matter

Comment: @Felix The op provided big endian data, which is all we care about. You're introducing a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

First off: There is no such functionality in QByteArray. There are ways around it however, as long as you know how long the bytearray will be. There is however one tiny thing that makes this extra complicated: [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

The following example assumes all your bytearrays have a maximum length. The function is generic, so you can decide dynamically if required:

```
template <typename TInt>
void addNumber(QByteArray &data, TInt number) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<TInt>::value, "TInt must be an integral type");

    constexpr auto maxSize = sizeof(TInt);
    const auto dSize = data.size();

    // make shure no data that is longer then the allowed integer size is passed
    Q_ASSERT_X(dSize <= maxSize, Q_FUNC_INFO, "bytearrays longer than sizeof(TInt) byte are not allowed!");

    // prepend '\0' bytes to the array to fill it up to an N byte length
    if(dSize < maxSize)
        data = QByteArray{maxSize - dSize, '\0'} + data;

    // convert to a number, add and convert back
    auto dataNum = qFromBigEndian<TInt>(data.constData());
    dataNum += number;
    qToBigEndian(dataNum, data.data());

    // resize the data back to the original size, dropping the previously prepended bytes
    if(dSize < maxSize)
        data = data.mid(maxSize - dSize);
}
```

To use the method, simply find out how long your bytearrays can be and then use the method with the according type. For example, if your data is limited to at most 4 bytes (as specified in the commencts), you could use it as:

```
QByteArray ba = "\x8a\x0d\x8a";
addNumber<quint32>(ba, 1u);
// ba is now "\x8a\x0d\x8b"
```

**Important:** Be careful with the template argument. specify it explicitly to ensure you do not accidentially pass a literal of a different type. For example, calling it as simply `addNumber(ba, 1)` will deduce `TInt` as `int` - not an unsinged int.

**EDIT:**
In case you define your bytearrays endianness to be the same as the current plattform, no such conversion is needed. The code would change to:

```
// convert to a number, add and convert back
*(reinterpret_cast<TInt*>(data.data())) += number;
```

It really depends on where this data comes from and how you use it.

Comment: There are no endianness problems here... it's a **byte array**.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist the number has an endianness defined by the platform, the bytearray has an endianness defined by OP. They might differ

Comment: @Caleth Look at my solution and see how endianness doesn't matter unless you make it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist "It can have 3 or 4 elements" You answer assumes 4. This does not.

Comment: @Caleth And why does it matter for endianness whether it's 3 or 4? My answer works for both because the forth byte can be zero. This is a proof of concept. You can make it all kinds of fancy by putting it in a loop.

Comment: Endianness might matter, as it defines how the bytearray should be interpreted. If we assume OP has the bytearray in BE format, that we have to convert it to the one of the plattform. If OP of course defines endianness of the bytearray to be the same as integers on the current plattform, no conversion is needed

Comment: @Felix If you cast that array to a uint32_t, it might matter. But you don't have to cast it that way. Just use addition like I did in my solution. You're introducing an endianness problem while it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple data like

```
template <typename T> union BData
{
     uint8_t data[sizeof(T)];
     T value;
 };
```

Then you can perform your arithmetic operations and extract bytes from the union. However you should be aware of endiness.